How do XCR0 and XSTATE work for AVX10.2/256?
In order to use AVX-512, the processor must support AVX-512 and certain bits of the register XCR0 must be set by the OS kernel.  For AVX-512, these XCR0 bits are:

1: indicates saving support for XMM0-XMM15.
2: indicates saving support for the high halves of YMM0-YMM15.
5: indicates saving support for K0-K7.
6: indicates saving support for the high halves of ZMM0-ZMM15.
7: indicates saving support for ZMM16-ZMM31.

But what about upcoming processors with AVX10.2 that only support 256-bit vectors?  What bits of XCR0 will be set, and which portions of "XSTATE" will be valid?  Intel's AVX10 documentation doesn't say anything about what happens to the bits of XCR0 in this case.
For AVX10.2/256, are bits 1, 2, 5 and 7 set, but not 6?  Bit 6 would indicate that the high 256 bits of ZMM0-ZMM15 would be saved to XSTATE, but those high halves would not actually exist in a 256-bit-vector AVX10.2 processor.
For bits 5 and 7, are they supported, but the high halves of the K0-K7 and ZMM16-ZMM31 in XSTATE simply zeroed out?  Or is a different XSTATE layout used for 256-bit-only AVX10 processors?
